# Second-order Lagrange condition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am not sure what the second-order Lagrange condition is and how it applies to this?

Minimize $x^2 + y^2$

Subject to $x^2 - y - 4 \leq 0$ and $y - x - 2 \leq 0$.

Please can someone assist me in the steps/process to solve this using the Second-order Lagrange condition??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to apply Lagrange Multiplier for inequality constrain, i.e. [KKT conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

So we have two inequality constrains and we have to look into $2^2=4$ distinct cases, and the initial function:

$$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$

becomes:

$$F(x,y,\lambda,\lambda_1) = x^2 + y^2 + \lambda(x^2 - y - 4) - \lambda_1(y-x-2)$$

Now we take partial derivatives and set them to $0$:

$$F_x = 2x + 2\lambda x + \lambda_1 = 0$$
$$F_y = 2y - \lambda - \lambda_1 = 0$$
$$F_{\lambda} = x^2 - y - 4 = 0$$
$$F_{\lambda_1} = y-x-2 = 0$$

Now we check all the cases:

**Case 1: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = 0$**

If we substitute back into the parital derivatives we get that $2x = 0 \implies x = 0$ and $2y = 0 \implies y = 0$. So we obtain one solution:

$$(x,y) = (0,0)$$

We can chech that that solution fulfil the constrains.

**Case 2: $\lambda = y-x-2 = 0$**

If we set $F_x = F_y$ we get: $y - x = \lambda_1 \implies \lambda_1 = 2 $. Now substituting back we have: $y= 1$ and $x=-1$. So we obtained another solution:

$$(x,y) = (-1,1)$$

**Case 3: $x^2-y-4 = \lambda_1=0$**

$F_x$ can be rearranged as $2x(1+\lambda) = 0$, becasue, the gradient $\lambda$ must be non-negative so we have $x=0$. From the condition we have that $y = -4$. So we have another solution:

$$(x,y) = (0,-4)$$

**Case 4: $x^2-y-4 = y-x-2=0$**

From the condition we can get: $y = x + 2$ and plugging into the first equation we have:

$$x^2 - y - 4 = 0$$
$$x^2 - x - 2 - 4 = 0$$
$$x^2 - x - 6 = 0$$

Solving this quadratic equation we have: $x_1 = 3$ and $x_2 = -2$. For $y$ we have $y=5$ and $y = 0$ respectively.

So we obtain two solutions:

$$(x,y) = (3,5), (-2,0)$$

Plugging those five solutions into the initial function, we can check that the minima occurs at $f(0,0) = 0$ and the maxima occurs at $f(3,5) = 9 + 25 = 34$

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense. I will try it with another one as well.

Comment: It's good that you understand this method. One additional advise, sometimes there won't be a stationary on the interior of the region, so we need to check the boundaries of the region. This often happens when we restrict a variable on non-negative values so one constrain is $x\ge 0$. And if we were not able to find a stationary point in the interior, then we need to set $x$ to 0, because the region is bounded just from one side. Sometimes if there were more variables and constrains like that, thne you need to check the case when $y=0$ and both $x=y=0$